# Is gluing the boundary of $2$ discs removed from a surface also a surface?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a surface $S$. Also, suppose we remove $2$ discs from the surface $S$ and we glue the boundary circles of these two discs together. Is the result a surface?

My beliefis that it is a sphere. But I am not sure how to show it. Can someone help me see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get a sphere. If you start with a sphere, then you come up with a cylinder when you delete $2$ discs from it. Now if you glue these two boundaries, you get either a torus or a Klein bottle, depending on how you glue the two boundaries.